# In Google play store what happens if beta tester version is higher than production version

Tags: android, google-play

In google play store 
production : release not live 
version : 2

Beta tester review : release not live 
version : 3

then if I click to review and publish then what happens

Comment: This is explained in [the Play Console help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en) (expand the section named **Version code requirements**).

Comment: I have a doubt if i click to button "review and publish" means production app published or not

Comment: AFAIK all updates that are ready to publish will be published.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.